# How to find a laser straight line?

Tags: ros, laser, sensor, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to user laser for finding some obstacles. So I would like to know how to work with straight lines on laser scan massages. So if the points are the longer straight lines of the sensor massage means the obstacle is a wall. If not than its a something else.. Cause I need to distinguish between a wall and some other tall object. But I dont know how to find the straight line the laser scan sensor massage. Any help??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66295/how-to-find-a-laser-straight-line?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) for finding lines.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-01**:
But I dont wont to use depth images and kinect. Only laser. So how does Hough Transform  work to identify straight lines in laser scans???

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-07-02**:
For the Hough Transform, the point data from a laser is just fine. It will probably be easiest to do things in the laser's frame so you can treat all the points as 2d.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-02**:
ok. Thanks. Any help or example code of Hough Transform and ROS???